# How to move a movie from Camera Roll to app's Documents folder?

Tags: iphone

How can I copy/move a movie from Camera Roll to an app's own Documents folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` like this –

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL * fileURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.MOV"];

    NSError * error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileURL
                                            toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]
                                            error:&error];

    if ( error ) 
        NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Once the user selects a movie, you get a file URL to a temporary file using the key `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` in the `info` dictionary passed as argument to the delegate method. You can get that and then copy the file to the documents directory using `NSFileManager`.

Comment: getting nil value in fileURL